# how can i fix the dhl shipping error?

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping-methods, dhl

I have been added the all information about dhl in `magento system >> configuration >> sales >> shipping method` but all information about dhl is correct even i had confirmed with dhl office and all info are correct.

But still getting the error from DHL in front-end.

> DHL
>       This shipping method is currently unavailable in this location. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.

[image]

```
2015-10-09T12:05:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:DCTRequest xmlns:p="http://www.dhl.com" xmlns:p1="http://www.dhl.com/datatypes" xmlns:p2="http://www.dhl.com/DCTRequestdatatypes" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dhl.com DCT-req.xsd "><GetQuote xmlns=""><Request><ServiceHeader><SiteID>EMUESIRI</SiteID><Password>dHQIl6aesu</Password></ServiceHeader></Request><From><CountryCode>NG</CountryCode><Postalcode>904103</Postalcode><City>Abuja</City></From><BkgDetails><PaymentCountryCode>NG</PaymentCountryCode><Date>2015-10-09</Date><ReadyTime>PT0H00M</ReadyTime><DimensionUnit>CM</DimensionUnit><WeightUnit>KG</WeightUnit><Pieces xmlns=""><Piece xmlns=""><PieceID>1</PieceID><Weight>0.1</Weight></Piece></Pieces><PaymentAccountNumber>365081821</PaymentAccountNumber></BkgDetails><To><CountryCode>NG</CountryCode><Postalcode>450211</Postalcode><City>Asa </City></To></GetQuote></p:DCTRequest>

    [__pid] => 6197
)

2015-10-09T12:05:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => Error parsing body - doesn't seem to be a chunked message
    [1] => The response is in wrong format.
    [__pid] => 6197
)
```

Comment: check your log file shipping_dhlint.log  located at var/log and paste your request and response here

Comment: have you added Origin address in Shipping Settings ?

Comment: FYI do not share your account number here any one can create shipment by using that account number

Comment: @MineshPatel i have added the shipping_dhlint error, please..

Comment: It seems your response is empty

Comment: Debug your application by setting Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);  in your index.php file

Comment: any update here ?

Comment: i got it, it was error in magento  less than ce 1.8 version which 2015-10-09T12:05:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => Error parsing body - doesn't seem to be a chunked message
    [1] => The response is in wrong format.
    [__pid] => 6197
)

Comment: this error is default erro in magento and i replaced new magento version 1.9x curl.php then it is working now !

Comment: Anyone help me DHL Updates not save error, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/220467/57334

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the "**Content-type**" to "Non-documents" and "**Allowed Methods**" to "Express Worldwide".